# What is currently the best way to add a custom dictionary to a neural machine translator that uses the transformer architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, seq2seq, machine-translation

It's common to add a custom dictionary to a machine translator to ensure that terminology from a specific domain is correctly translated. For example, the term server should be translated differently when the document is about data centers, vs when the document is about restaurants.

With a transformer model, this is not very obvious to do, since words are not aligned 1:1. I've seen a couple of papers on this topic, but I'm not sure which would be the best one to use. What are the best practices for this problem?

Comment: As of 2021, this remains an open research question.